# How to remove a Geofence from Geofence list?

Tags: java, android, gps, geofencing, android-geofence

I'm working on a simple app that creates geofences and detexts when the user enter/move/exit that area.
I'm trying to remove a geofence when the user enter that specific geofence, but I can' find any documentation on how to implement this.

Im creating two geofences.

Testing on an emulator

```
private void addGeofence(LatLng latLng, float radius, String GEO_ID) {
    Geofence geofence = geofenceHelper.getGeofence(GEO_ID, latLng, radius, Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT);
    GeofencingRequest geofencingRequest = geofenceHelper.geofencingRequest(geofence);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = geofenceHelper.getPendingIntent();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    geofencingClient.addGeofences(geofencingRequest, pendingIntent).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Geocenfe added");
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            String errorMessage = geofenceHelper.getErrorString(e);
            Log.e("TAG", "onFailure: " + errorMessage);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onFailure: " + errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}




public class GeofenceBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);

        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            Log.e("TAG", "onReceive: Error geofence event...");
            return;
        }

        List<Geofence> geofenceList = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();
        for (Geofence geofence: geofenceList) {
            Log.e("TAG", "ID: " + geofence.getRequestId());
        }

        int transitionType = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();
        switch (transitionType) {
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER: 
                Log.e("TAG", "GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER: ");
                break;
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL:
//                Log.e("TAG", "GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL: "); 
                break;
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
                Log.e("TAG", "GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT: "); 
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the correct documentation, either for removing a List of geofences, or all of them together.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingClient#removeGeofences(java.util.List%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)

Here a simple implementation given your Code:

```
private void removeGeofence(List<String> geofenceRequestIds) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    if(geofenceRequestIds != null) {
        geofencingClient.removeGeofences(geofenceRequestIds).addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> Log.e("TAG", "Geocenfences removed")).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            String errorMessage = geofenceHelper.getErrorString(e);
            Log.e("TAG", "onFailure: " + errorMessage);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onFailure: " + errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG,"no list provided, removing ALL geofences");
        geofencingClient.removeGeofences(geofenceHelper.getPendingIntent()).addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> Log.e("TAG", "Geocenfences removed")).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            String errorMessage = geofenceHelper.getErrorString(e);
            Log.e("TAG", "onFailure: " + errorMessage);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onFailure: " + errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });;
    }
}
```

Not having access to your geofencehelper, make sure you use the FLAG_MUTABLE together with FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT for it's getPendingIntent() if targeting API 31 or above, else the triggering Geofences will contain no Intent data.